# How to call a method that include a block as a parameter and NSString as the block parameter

Tags: ios, objective-c-blocks

I have a method like this

```
-(void)GetPostPreperation :(NSMutableURLRequest *)request :(BOOL)isGet :(NSMutableDictionary *)jsonBody :(void(^)(NSString*)) compblock
```

how can I pass parameter into this within a block? I tried like this. but it giving me an syntax error, `Expected Expression`

This is the way I tried

```
 [self GetPostPreperation:request :isGet :jsonBody :(^NSString*)str
 {
     return str;

 }];
```

This is how I defined my block

```
typedef void(^myCompletion)(NSString *);
```

I want to assign a `NSString` value to the block parameter within my `GetPostPreperation` method and check  and return it from the block calling method.How can I do this? Please help me.
Thanks

Comment: what you want means you are asking about how to use typedef or something else

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use it in this way,here `str` is an input not return

```
[self GetPostPreperation:request :true : jsonBody :^(NSString * str) {
        //here use
        NSLog(@"%@",str);

    }];
```

**Update**

do not return anything from this block.The block type is `void(^)(NSString*)`,the return is void

Comment: Hello thnnks for the answer but for me it giving  an error like this  Incompatible block pointer types sending 'NSString *(^)(NSString *__strong)' to parameter of type 'void (^)(NSString *__strong)'

Comment: Post the full code about how you use this function,I guess you put return something from this block.The block return is void.You do not need to return

Comment: I think he need to use typedef for block, I'm right or I misunderstood ?

Answer (score 2):

```
[self GetPostPreperation:nil :YES :nil :^(NSString * string) {
  //your code
  NSLog(@"%@", string);
}];
```

I would also suggest you to change the method definition as below:

```
-(void)GetPostPreperation :(NSMutableURLRequest *)request
                          :(BOOL)isGet :(NSMutableDictionary *)jsonBody
                          :(void(^)(NSString* string)) compblock
```

This will give you auto suggestion when typing this method and you can just hit enter to create it.

[image]

Comment: Incompatible block pointer types sending 'NSString *(^)(NSString *__strong)' to parameter of type 'void (^)(NSString *__strong)'  Im getting this error. Why is that/

Comment: Why are you returning string from a `void` block? if you want that, you need to change the return type

Answer (score 1):

just make block with String parameter and pass that block to method.

like below

```
void (/*Block name*/^failure)(/*block formal parameter*/NSError *) = ^(/*block actual parameter*/NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Error is:%@",error);
    };

[self myMethod:failure];
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare variable name in block so you can access it while using that block (string)

```
// typedef of block    
    typedef void(^myCompletion)(NSString * string);



        NSMutableURLRequest * req = [NSMutableURLRequest new];
            NSMutableDictionary * dict = [NSMutableDictionary new];

       /// method calling     
            [self GetPostPreperation:req
                               isGet:true
                            jsonBody:dict
                               block:^(NSString *string) {
                                   if ([string isEqualToString:@"xyz"]) {

                                   }
                                   else
                                   {

                                   }
                               }];
```

When ever your method have more than one argument then it will always write as like follow (i.e. isGet:(BOOL)isGet) so it easy while calling that method

// method with block

```
    -(void)GetPostPreperation :(NSMutableURLRequest *)request isGet:(BOOL)isGet jsonBody:(NSMutableDictionary *)jsonBody block:(myCompletion)string
    {
        string(@"yes");

    }
```